# Is it possible to get GitLab web editor through Gitlab API

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab, gitlab-api

My project is about configuration management. And I used Gitlab API for configuration version control.

So, I want to make some web online editor that can edit some files in Gitlab's repository. Editor like this

[image]
Can I get web editor component from Gitlab through Gitlab API?

If not. Can you suggest me some web online editor that can brought to my web project?

PS. My project use laravel tool for web app.

Thank you.